# Register multiple SPI ports (devices) to single SPI Platform Driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, spi

I'm developing a Linux spi driver to handle communication via SPI port.
My SoC offers three spi modules (which I understand it as ports) called ecspi1/ecspi2/ecspi3.
I have needs to send two kinds of data using ecspi1 and ecspi2.

I've implemented a driver which registered to spi driver and already successfully handled ecspi1 by add below to dts and driver:

[ dts ]

```
&ecspi1 {
    status = "okay";

    fpga1: lfe5u12f6bg256i@0 {
        reg = <0>;
        compatible = "lattice,lfe5u12f6bg256i";
        spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
    };
};
```

[ driver ]

```c
static const struct of_device_id fpga_spi_of_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "lattice,lfe5u12f6bg256i", },
    {},
};
```

I've tried to add ecspi2 to driver with below modifications.
However, driver's probed twice on boot and failed at the second probe period.

[ dts ]

```
 &ecspi1 {
    status = "okay";

    fpga1: lfe5u12f6bg256i@0 {
        reg = <0>;
        compatible = "lattice,lfe5u12f6bg256i";
        spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
    };
 };

+&ecspi2 {
+   status = "okay";
+
+   fpga0: fpga_fw@0 {
+       reg = <0>;
+       compatible = "fpga_fw,lfe5u12f6bg256i";
+       spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
+   };
+};
```

[ driver ]

```
 static const struct of_device_id fpga_spi_of_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "fpga_fw,lfe5u12f6bg256i", },
+   { .compatible = "lattice,lfe5u12f6bg256i", },
    {},
 };
```

Does anyone know how to handle multiple SPI ports (devices) in single driver?

Comment: Can you show your module init function and the probe function?

Comment: If you need more than one, you need to register them in `->init()` callback. Driver will be platform in this case (as multi-instantiate of SPI slave devices). I think you might find examples in the kernel.

Comment: @0andriy Thank you for your advice. I realized that it should be modified to suit multi-instantiate.

Comment: It appears that you don't need it. There's a standard mechanism to enumerate as described in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle two identical SPI devices with the same driver, the driver doesn't need to be modified and needs only one compatible string:

DTS:

```
&ecspi1 {
    status = "okay";

    fpga1: lfe5u12f6bg256i@0 {
        reg = <0>;
        compatible = "lattice,lfe5u12f6bg256i";
        spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
    };
 };

&ecspi2 {
    status = "okay";

    fpga2: lfe5u12f6bg256i@0 {
        reg = <0>;
        compatible = "lattice,lfe5u12f6bg256i";
        spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
    };
 };
```

Driver:

```
static const struct of_device_id fpga_spi_of_match[] = {
    { .compatible = "lattice,lfe5u12f6bg256i", },
    {},
};
```

The driver will be instantiated twice, once for each device, and each time it will receive a different `struct spi_device`.

Comment: Your suggestion works for me, thank you very much.
However, there is a mistake in your answer for DTS. Label name (fpga1: lfe5u12f6bg256i@0) shouldn't be same although they have same compatible string. It will cause "Duplicate label" error. So just modifying the compatible string will be fine enough.
After all, thank you for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Good to know it was helpful and thanks for reporting the mistake, I just fixed the reply.